# How to rewrite the result of encode as String representation?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a model

```
class ProfileData {
  final String id;
  final String photo;
  final String text;

  const ProfileData(this.id, this.photo, this.text);
  ...

  static Map<String, dynamic> toJson(ProfileData data) {
    return {
      "id": data.id,
      "photo": data.photo,
      "text": data.text,
    };
  }

  static String encode(List<ProfileData> list) => json.encode(
        list.map<Map<String, dynamic>>((item) => ProfileData.toJson(item)).toList(),
      );
```

later in the code

```
String favorites = (prefs.getString('favorites') ??
    ProfileData.encode(<ProfileData>[
      ProfileData('id1', 'photo1', 'text data 1'),
      ProfileData('id2', 'photo2', 'text data 2'),
    ]));
```

The result of `encode` is String, then how to rewrite the right part of the condition as a string representation, in case when the left part condition is null?

Comment: @pskink this one ??

Comment: ok, and what is the problem actually with `ProfileData.encode(<ProfileData>[ ...`?

Comment: @pskink right there

Comment: `ProfileData.encode` returns a `String` so whats the problem with it?

Comment: What you want is to hardocde the serialized models like : `prefs.getString('favorites') ??'''[
{"id":"id1","photo": "photo1","text": "text data 1"},
{"id":"id2","photo": "photo2","text": "text data 2"},
    ]'''` ? Is that it?